# How to ignore Eclipse workspace .metadata folder in Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, eclipse

I'm a Eclipse's user and I want synchronize my workspace on Ubuntu One. The problem is because the Eclipse creates a metadata inside of workspace, this meta have some configurations of computer that use this program.

So, when I sync my workspace folder, this meta go with all my projects, and when I download it in another computer, Ubuntu One overrides the meta folder and crashes my Eclipse.

There is some way of share a folder on Ubuntu One, but eliminate some internal folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hidden configuration option, which you can add a list of Python (not shell) expressions to, for ignoring specific file extensions for example. In the `~/.config/ubuntuone/syncdaemon.conf` file you can add the following:

```
[__main__]
ignore = \A.*\.metadata\Z
```

This should keep the .metadata folder from being synchronized. If the file already exists, and has an existing `[__ main __]` (without spaces) section, don't add another one.

You should stop ubuntuone-syncdaemon by running `u1sdtool -q` in a terminal, first. Then make your changes, and run `u1sdtool -c` to restart and connect the syncdaemon.

Comment: Nice answer! Can you provide more info on that trick? I'm confused about the \A-\Z syntax.

Comment: @rafalcieslak http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax \A is "match only at start" and \Z is "match only at end" similar to ^ and $ in other regular expression implementations, respectively.

Comment: Thank you!!!! Work like a charm!!! For someone who want try this, you will need reboot your pc!!

Comment: @GuilhermeFranco Ah, actually you don't need to reboot. You can run u1sdtool -q in a terminal to quit the syncdaemon, and u1sdtool -c to start it back up after making the changes. Should have put that in the answer too.

Comment: At my other computer I have tried it (using gui) but it not worked... then I had reboot.  Now, at my notebook, it works..... I don't know what happened on my desktop for that not worked properly..... thanks a lot!!

Comment: The control panel (gui) only disconnects and connects the syncdaemon from/to the network. It remains running, and monitoring the files, so that when you connect back to the network, things will update without having to wait for the hashing to happen. Rebooting would have certainly restarted the whole process. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a cron job that recursively copies, thus leaving out the .whatever files.  Then you can sync the whole thing of the copy.  I don't use ubuntuone(I'm skeptical about all things cloud), so I'm not "up" on its configuration options, but I use a similar approach for some of the stuff I throw on github.